# google maps initialization stuck in storybook

Tags: javascript, google-maps, storybook

I am looking for some help  from specialists as I was not able to find any issues similar to what I am facing today.
So I am trying to use google-maps with storybook. My code has already worked with many other preview solution but I don't know why something is wrong with storybook
So the google-maps api is loaded with a component and then my code initialize the map with a simple call new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'))

I don't know why the map object initialization never finished and when I am looking to internal object `__gm` with google chrome development tool, i can see :

```
{
    ...
    renderingType: "UNINITIALIZED",
    ...
    __gm: {
        isInitialized: false,
        isMapBindingComplete: false,
        o: {
            [[Prototype]]: Promise,
            [[PromiseState]]: "pending",
            [[PromiseResult]]:  undefined
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I can see the placeholder image used until the initialization is finished but the dynamic map is never added

[storybook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W4dI.png)

The story book code:

```
export const Map: ComponentStory<typeof MyMaps> = () => {


  function initOtherMap() {    
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {center: { lat: 40.747445, lng: -74.000704 }, zoom: 12});
    setTimeout(() => console.info("debug", "map", map), 500);
  }

  
  setTimeout(() => initOtherMap(), 2000);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <div id="map-container" style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px', border: '1px solid' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I don't know what to look for now because the SDK code is not public and I have no error in the console explaining why the initialization process never ends.
Any idea on how I can track the loading process or getting more information on what is happening? Thank you !

I have tried to add some log in google maps sdk but the minimized code make the initialization process obscure

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting problems with Google Maps in Storybook can be challenging, especially when the error is invisible. You can follow the steps below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const Map = (props) => {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Load the Google Maps script
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE`;
    script.async = true;

    // Initialize the map once the script is loaded
    script.onload = () => {
      if (mapContainerRef.current) {
        new google.maps.Map(mapContainerRef.current, {
          center: { lat: 40.747445, lng: -74.000704 },
          zoom: 12,
        });
      }
    };

    // Handle script loading errors
    script.onerror = () => {
      console.error('Google Maps API failed to load');
    };

    // Append the script to the document head
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    // Clean up the script element on component unmount
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <div ref={mapContainerRef} style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px', border: '1px solid' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have both UseEffect and useRef Hook to ensure that it only initialized once after the component mount

Comment: I have tried adding listeners but no log

Comment: You might be having this issue due to many reasons, but I will put a complete code for you to ensure you change the sample API URL to yours. let me know if that work.

Comment: I have use a local copy of google-maps sdk and add some trace and I am sure that this file is used and is correctly loaded. As you can see in the screenshot linked in the original post, the static image placeholder used until the initialization completion is visible but the initialization process never ends: the promise `__gm.o` is left in a pending state but I dont know what is behind this promise and on which step it is located